# Different dimens.xml based on device resolution

Tags: android, xml, scaling, dimensions

I'm having some trouble creating dimens.xml for different screen sizes of my landscape tablet app.

I have for now created the following structure:

```
values\dimens.xml
values-sw600dp\dimens.xml
values-sw800dp\dimens.xml
values-sw1080dp\dimens.xml
```

Along with the following emulators

```
7" 600 x 1024: mdpi
10" 800 x 1280: mdpi
10" 1080 x 1920: hdpi
```

The problem is that when i change any dp size in `values-sw600dp\dimens.xml` this will be what all the emulators read. What am i missing?

Comment: I'd suggest to go for [SDP](https://github.com/intuit/sdp) for layout sizes and [SSP](https://github.com/intuit/ssp) for text sizes. I know these are libraries but I've been using them in one of my kotlin project and it works well for almost every size of device I've tested.

Answer (score 2):

You are mixing dp and pixels, they are not the same. Your folders should follow this structure

```
values
values-sw600dp
values-sw720dp
```

The first will apply to phones, the 2nd to medium tablets (7-8") while the last will apply to large tablets.

See [this](https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes) for reference.